# pass an alternative link to wget when downloading pictures/files on error

Tags: wget

`wget`is a great tool to download files or webpages. It is not the first timke that I find that the links of a webpage are not updated or wrong. For instance, a web page which has its pictures/files linked with `http://websitehttp//website.file.extension`.
Is there a way to tell `wget` that, if no content is found, it has to look in the address `http//website.file.extension` instead of `http://websitehttp//website.file.extension`?

EDIT: Following @Tigger's comment, I can get exit status but how to ask wget for that specific file that failed to get it on the right link/address?

```
wget_output=$(wget –limit-rate=200k –no-clobber –convert-links –random-wait -r -p -E "$URL")
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  ...
fi
```

Comment: `wget` will exit `0` if there are no errors and from 1 to 8 on another kind of error (see exit status in man page). You could use the exit status within a simply shell script to work out when to try a second link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple script that might help you to get started:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Make sure a URL is passed first
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    echo "
Pass the full URL to be downloaded. For example:

 ${0##*/} \"http://websitehttp/website.file.extension\"

If that URL fails, then \"http://website.file.extension\"
will be tried automatically.
"
    exit 1
fi

# Attempt download
wget -v "${1}"

# Check for an error and if so, try an alternative download
if [ "$?" != "0" ]
then
    url2=`echo ${1} | cut -d '/' -f 4-`
    # DEBUG echo "[$url2]"
    wget -v "http://${url2}"
fi

echo "Done"
exit 0
```

Comment: thanks again. I have tested the script but please note that I am doing a recursive call to an url and therefore I do not know in advance the complete link address of the different webpages. I only know that some links are wrong because the parent "www.website.com" is duplicated in the link to some files in some webpages.

Comment: If you are doing a recursive crawl and the links are wrong then there is very little you can do. My understanding is `wget` can not guess what the correct link should have been :] One option might be to create a `wget` log file and then parse the errors in the log file (using a script).